# The PHP form information is not being inserted into the database

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to insert Form information into the database.A very simple code.

I've verified to all the other answers in the site but it does not work

```
        <?php 
        session_start();

    // variable declaration
    $school_name= "";
    $dob = "";
    $stu_name = "";
    $stu_id = "";
    $class = "";
    $section = "";
    $project = "";
    $_SESSION['success'] = "";

    // connect to database
  $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  global $db;
  global $dbcreate;
  //creating database
  $dbcreate="CREATE DATABASE student";
  $retval=mysql_query($dbcreate,$db);
  //Creating table
  mysql_select_db("student",$db);


    if (isset($_POST['add'])){
        // receive all input values from the form
        $school_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['school_name']);
        $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
        $stu_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['stu_name']);
        $stu_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['stu_id']);
        $class = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['class']);
        $section = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['section']);
    $project = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['project']);
  }
      //Insert the data into the tables
      if(isset($_POST['add'])){
    $sql1="INSERT INTO  student(school_name,dob,stu_name,stu_id,class,section,project)
    VALUES ({$_POST['school_name']},{$_POST['dob']},{$_POST['stu_name']},{$_POST['stu_id']},{$_POST['class']},{$_POST['section']},{$_POST['project']})";
    $insertquery=mysql_query($sql1,$db);
      }


  ?>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="login-box">
  <h1>Students Details</h1>
  <form method="post" action="login.php">


  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="School Name" name="school_name"value="<?php echo $school_name;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Date" name="dob"value="<?php echo $dob;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student Name" name="stu_name"value="<?php echo $stu_name;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Student Id" name="stu_id"value="<?php echo $stu_id;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="class" name="class"value="<?php echo $class;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Section" name="section"value="<?php echo $section;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="textbox">
    <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Project" name="project"value="<?php echo $project;?>">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn" name="add" href="login.php">Add details </button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected the information to be saved in the database.
I went on to check the database in localhost/phpmyadmin.

But  nothing is saved.
don't worry about the deprecated old mysql function I'm using a old version of XAMPP

Comment: Look like your script just creates `student` database, where is your `student` table?

Comment: Your SQL is invalid. Your PHP is insecure and using a deprecated/removed driver. You should use error reporting. You don't need `global` if you aren't using functions, your script is already in the global scope.

Comment: Is it your login.php page?. If its not post method can not achieve your php script. Baceuse your action is login.php

Comment: Need to enclose strings in apostrophes in your SQL command. i.e.  '{$_POST['stu_name']}'

Comment: Why is mysql_real_escape_string called however the results aren't used in the SQL query? Probably the same reason as the solution presented, syntax error. Taking the right approach to SQL injection is prevented by PDO, and never string concatenation would of fixed this earlier.

Comment: I have to wonder just how old the versions are that you installed and for what reason. Are you updating some very old code? if that's the case with such a leap it might be better to start afresh on a recent release and begin your learning process there. I see no reason for learning functions and coding practices that have long since been deprecated if not already removed in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

You are using string operations to populate a query. Never do this! Most languages and DB libraries will provide parameterized query functionality; PHP makes you jump through a slightly different hoop for this. Use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) to ensure your string values, which are not quoted here, are both properly escaped *and* enquoted.

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
    if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
        // receive all input values from the form
        $school_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['school_name']);
        $dob = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dob']);
        $stu_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['stu_name']);
        $stu_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['stu_id']);
        $class = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['class']);
        $section = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['section']);
        $project = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['project']);

        $sql1="INSERT INTO student(school_name,dob,stu_name,stu_id,class,section,project)
               VALUES ('{$school_name}', '{$dob}', '{$stu_name}', '{$stu_id}', '{$class}', '{$section}', '{$project}')";
        $insertquery = mysql_query($sql1, $db);
    }
```

you're also creating a database every time, only need to do this ONCE, but also need to create the table ONCE.

Comment: If you're going to down vote at least have the courtesy and courage to explain why.  My original answer addressed his question, I wasn't trying to optimize his code.

Comment: I edited your answer, but the downvote is not from me.